# How to HTTP POST a Unicoded Japanese data in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-2.7, unicode

Trying to mine data off my institute's web server. (With permission, of course.)
Since I could not bring the codes back with me, I am sorry but I can only provide some snippets.

The intranet webpage's charset is 'euc-jp', I had tried encode and POST both utf-8 and euc-jp to the website but it still doesn't accept my payload. Payload here means that the webpage doesn't accept the passed parameters and defined it as invalid values. The most possible culprit should be the BEGINTIME, ENDTIME and showBtn's value. According to the webmaster, he personally tried sending utf-8 to the server and it seems like the webpage only accepts euc-jp.

Below is my code and I will include what I had tried after my codes.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stdin = codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin)
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

from lxml import html
import requests

POST_PAGE = 'http://www-cont.randomserverwebpage.jp/zLog/frame_showSearchResults'

#Login
USERNAME = 'randomusername'
PASSWORD = 'randompassword'

#Parameters needed to be passed in URLs
#NOT CONFIRM if the 0:00 should be inside a pair of parenthesises
msYear = 2007
msMonth = 11
msDay = 19
meYear = 2007
meMonth = 11
meDay = 20
payload = {unicode('SELECT_GROUP').encode('euc-jp'): unicode('ALL').encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('SELECT_SX').encode('euc-jp'): unicode('NONE').encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('KEY1').encode('euc-jp'): unicode('').encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('KEY2').encode('euc-jp'): unicode('').encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('KEY3').encode('euc-jp'): unicode('').encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('LOGYYYYS').encode('euc-jp'): unicode(msYear).encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('LOGMMS').encode('euc-jp'): unicode(msMonth).encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('LOGDDS').encode('euc-jp'): unicode(msDay).encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('BEGINTIME').encode('euc-jp'): unicode('0:00').encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('LOGYYYYE').encode('euc-jp'): unicode(meYear).encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('LOGMME').encode('euc-jp'): unicode(meMonth).encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('LOGDDE').encode('euc-jp'): unicode(meDay).encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('ENDTIME').encode('euc-jp'): unicode('0:00').encode('euc-jp'),
       unicode('showBtn').encode('euc-jp'): unicode('表示（指定期間で）').encode('euc-jp')}

def crawl_search_page():
    global payload
    rheaders = {'content-type': 'text/html;charset=euc-jp'}
    r = requests.post(POST_PAGE, data=payload, headers=rheaders, auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD)).content
    r = r.decode('euc-jp')
    tree = html.fromstring(r)
    texts = tree.xpath('//title/text()')
    ff = open(FileName, 'w')
    for item in texts:
        ff.write(item)
    ff.close()

#Main
......
    while True:
        crawl_search_page()
        if ...:
            break
```

I also found out that I must put utf-8 in
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') or else the Japanese words will not be shown even in the

```
<title>randomJapaneseTitle ランダムジャパニーズタイトル</title>
```

After running the crawler/scraper, I got error 500. It is highly possible that I passed an invalid parameter/invalid unicoded showBtn. But, I may had missed something else too.

**NOTE**

utf-8 is only useful to decode other unicoded texts like what I did below with

```
r = r.decode('euc-jp')
```

Sending utf-8 to a webpage that only accepts euc-jp will not work. Because obviously, you are passing a totally different value to the webpage. So...

```
'showBtn': u'表示（指定期間で）'.encode('utf-8')
```

will NOT work. It is a totally different value to the button's euc-jp encoded value.  Nonetheless, I tried that as well.

**Update:** I am in the lab now so I can post what I got from r.content after decoding.
When the header is defined like this rheaders = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded, charset=euc-jp', 'content-encoding': 'gzip'}, it had become like what shown below. SELECT_SX not defined. Is there anything wrong about my payload definition? I think I may had defined the payload incorrectly. BTW, should I put text/html or application/x-www-form-urlencoded for the content type?

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content_type" content="text/html;charset=euc-jp">
  <head><title>randomJapaneseTitle ランダムジャパニーズタイトル</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">


  <h2>Site Error</h2>

  <p>An error was encountered while publishing this resource.
  </p>

  <p>
      <strong>Error Type: NameError</strong><br/>
      <strong>Error Value: name 'SELECT_SX' is not defined</strong><br/> 
  </p>

  <hr noshade="noshade" />

  <p>Troubleshooting Suggestions</p>

  <ul>
            <li>This resource may be trying to reference a
      nonexistent object or variable <strong>name 'SELECT_SX' is not defined</strong>.</li>
            <li>The URL may be incorrect.</li>
      <li>The parameters passed to this resource may be incorrect.</li>
      <li>A resource that this resource relies on may be encountering
          an error.</li>
  </ul>

  <p>For more detailed information about the error, please
  refer to the error log.
  </p>

  <p>If the error persists please contact the site maintainer.
  Thank you for your patience.
  </p>



  </body>
</html>
```

When the header is defined like this rheaders = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded, charset=euc-jp', 'content-encoding': 'gzip'}, below is what I got for error.

*note that the difference is the ';' and ',' between urlencoded and charset

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content_type" content="text/html;charset=euc-jp">
  <head><title>randomJapaneseTitle ランダムジャパニーズタイトル<</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">


  <h2>Site Error</h2>

  <p>An error was encountered while publishing this resource.
  </p>

  <p>
      <strong>Error Type: ProgrammingError</strong><br/>
      <strong>Error Value: ERROR:  relation &quot;none&quot; does not exist

select id,
       opetime as &quot;opetime_org&quot;,
       to_char(opetime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as &quot;opetime&quot;, 
       to_char(opetime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as &quot;opetime2&quot;,
       operation, comments,num_image,trouble_level,related_group
from   None
where
(trouble_level &lt;&gt; '0'
 and (active_flg = 1)
 and (hidden_flag = 0)
 and opetime between
      '2007-11-19 0:00' and to_timestamp('2007-11-20 0:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
)
order by 2 asc</strong><br/> 
  </p>

  <hr noshade="noshade" />

  <p>Troubleshooting Suggestions</p>

  <ul>
            <li>The URL may be incorrect.</li>
      <li>The parameters passed to this resource may be incorrect.</li>
      <li>A resource that this resource relies on may be encountering
          an error.</li>
  </ul>

  <p>For more detailed information about the error, please
  refer to the error log.
  </p>

  <p>If the error persists please contact the site maintainer.
  Thank you for your patience.
  </p>
```

Below is the **correct** parsed From Data obtained through inspecting elements with Chrome.

```
SELECT_GROUP=ALL&SELECT_SX=NONE&KEY1=&KEY2=&KEY3=&LOGYYYYS=2014&LOGMMS=9&LOGDDS=19&BEGINTIME=0%3A00&LOGYYYYE=2014&LOGMME=9&LOGDDE=22&ENDTIME=0%3A00&showBtn=%C9%BD%BC%A8%A1%CA%BB%D8%C4%EA%B4%FC%B4%D6%A4%C7%A1%CB
```

I know this might be a n00b question and you all have your own work. But anyone who spent their precious time helping will be greatly appreciated. I will update the page and explain what and how to solve the problem for future reference if this problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: did you try `'showBtn': u'表示（指定期間で）'.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: What do you mean by “doesn't accept my payload”, what happens? Note you have two separate problems here: getting data from the web server, and writing text to the file. The text you get from XPath `text()` will be in Unicode so you need to choose an encoding to write it to the file with, either by doing `ff.write(item.encode('utf-8'))` or by opening `ff = codecs.open(FileName, 'w', 'utf-8')`. Then you don't need the horrible hack that is `sys.setdefaultencoding'.

Comment: @Kasra, yes I had tried 'showBtn': u'表示（指定期間で）'.encode('utf-8')

Comment: @bobince yes, I also used that one but after trying a few things I settled down with the horrible hack, I will change it back. The reason I used sys.setdefaultencoding and coding: utf-8 is that the Japanese words in the html text didn't show up properly as Japanese text without using sys.setdefaultencoding

Comment: Did you try telling the server what charset the form text is encoded in?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sorry for my n00bness, but how?

Comment: In the `Content-Type` header, via the `charset` parameter.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am not sure, it is something like this?
headers={'content-type': 'text/html; charset=EUC-JP'}
then add r = requests.post(POST_PAGE, data=payload, headers=headers, auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD)).content?
Additional question, should I use params=payload instead of data=payload?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is the header ok?

Comment: If that's how you do a header, then sure. Make sure that it actually matches the encoding you're using though.